# Removing default borders from a POP UP Window

Tags: javascript, css

I am opening a POPUP Window using  window.open

please see the image here

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0ef7674

The default title blue color borders are appearing round the window 
as shown .

Can this be removed using CSS or any other option .

(I have seen Light box , but i am not using them )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is standard window chrome as provided by the GUI toolkit the browser uses. You cannot control it.

Comment: He took a step into the SO chatrooms and couldn't stop it flagging up an alert anytime anyone mentioned any David.